# Terminology - What is the correct term for an object inside another one?

Tags: geometry, terminology

In an n-dimensional Euclidean space, what is the correct term for an n-dimensional object inside another one? 
See [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujDb0.png/) as a three-dimensional example. Is saying "The smaller cube is inside of the bigger one" correct? Does that apply to 3+ dimensional Euclidean spaces? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Can "Contain" be used for line segments in 1-dimensional spaces?

Comment: Inscribed ?????

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I don't think so, sorry.

Comment: Inscribed would be appropriate if the boundary of the 'interior' object touched the exterior object's boundary in a maximal sense. (An inscribed triangle, for instance, is one which lies inside a circle and touched it at three points.) Perhaps one could say that the bigger cube contains the smaller cube? (The image used is a bit ambiguous, since without further information one can't really tell if the smaller cube is inside, behind, or in front of the larger cube.)

Comment: I think everybody would understand the word "inside". Technically, since regions are often though of as subsets of $\mathbb R^n$, you could denote this as $A \subseteq B$ and say in words that $A$ lies entirely inside $B$.

Comment: @Semiclassical Thank you, "Contain" sounds like the correct word here. The small cube is supposed to be inside the big one.

Comment: @RahulI I had doubted that "Inside" would sound too unformal (For the paper I'm currently trying to write). Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Object A is "suspended inside" object B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers from the comments:

- Inscribed (to be applied in the appropriate situation, where the inner set's boundary touches the outer set's boundary in a maximal sense, as a triangle inscribed in a disk)
- Contain (consider sets with interior and write $\subseteq$)
- Inside (perhaps not too informal)
- Suspended inside